# Magento2 - How to get cart sale-rules information with respect to specific Product?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, collection, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am using event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` which is triggered after Doing `Add to cart` any product, in the observer of this event I want to get associated cart price rule if any applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the ids of the rules applied to the quote separated by comma.

```
    public function __construct(
                                 ----------
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                                \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepositoryInterface,
                                 ----------
                               ) {
                                 $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
                                 $this->ruleRepositoryInterface = $ruleRepositoryInterface;
                               }



    $appliedRuleIds = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

if you want to get the rules applied as objects you can do this:

```
$appliedRuleIds = explode(',', $appliedRuleIds);

foreach ($appliedRuleIds as $appliedRuleId) {
    $this->ruleRepositoryInterface->getById($appliedRuleId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works perfectly for my Question,another things i want to know that ,suppose a scenario i defined for a cart price rule **buy X product and get Y Product at some discount** , suppose customer added X product  to cart how can we notify him about ** Y product **

Comment: welcome :). You can show some message/note at cart page based on the product in the cart.

Comment: sure ,i got your point but which filter have to be applied for this **X product** for getting it associated gift **(Discounted Y  product)** ,

Comment: Can you have any idear about this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305896/magento-2add-another-new-custom-mini-cart